# ping: sendmsg - no more space in buffer in Ubuntu 15

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, ping

My internet connection dropping very frequently and if I try to ping I get the message "ping: sendmsg - no more space in buffer". If I reconnect the wifi in works fine for sometime then it happens again.

I tried the following things:

- Increasing buffer.
- Changing router, previously I was using a netgear router, than I switched to Asus.
- Contacted with ISP, they couldn't detect problems.
- Tried with wired connection from router instead of wifi.

I saw several threads in internet on this issue but none could solve my problem.

My laptop is Asus Zenbook UX305.

Comment: Do you have access to a Wi-Fi USB dongle that you can try, instead of whatever Wi-Fi interface you're currently using on your Zenbook? Maybe your Zenbook's built-in Wi-Fi interface is buggy and choking and failing to transmit packets, which causes transmit queues to fill up.

Comment: Also, did you make sure you have the latest drivers for the Wi-Fi interface that you're using?

Comment: @spiff: How can I update drivers for wifi in Ubuntu? + I tried with wired connection too, same result.